# Transfer files between local to remote server using ssh without password authentication

Tags: linux, macos, authentication, ssh

I want to transfer some files from my local to remote, like github does it. I want to happend it very smooth like in shell script. I tried creating one shell script which automates the process of ssh authentication without password but for first time it exposes my remote server password. I dont want to do it that way. Like in git we can't see their server password. Is there any possible way that we can do ?

I used this article script to automate ssh login. http://www.techpaste.com/2013/04/shell-script-automate-ssh-key-transfer-hosts-linux/

Comment: You can use the `scp` with ssh key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned, you can use the scp command, like this:

```
scp /local_dir/some*.xml remote_user@remote_machine:/var/www/html
```

This requires that you need connect to the remote machine without password, only with ssh key-authentication.

Here is a link: http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html to help you.

The important steps: (automatic login from host A / user a to Host B / user b.)

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: Thank you @szpal for your answer I know that step but for last as we know that it needs password of my remote server to copy that file. I don't want to expose that thing.